how to ensure kernel threads do not access isolated CPU
I have a real time user level software stack running on ubuntu RT kernel.
Linux ran416 5.15.0-1061-realtime #69-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_RT Mon Apr 15 18:56:55 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I also configured CPU isolation and use set core affinity APIs to make some critical threads run on isolated CPU.
I ensured none other applications / threads are running on those isolated kernel (be it set core affinity or taskset)
So these eliminate any user application / threads from accessing my isolated core.
I ensured I am not doing any I/O, network operation or locking of any sort in the critical threads.
Still I see that kernel threads are sometime accessing the isolated cpu core in question. In such situation when my thread do not yield to kernel thread it causes system freeze. And in other cases it causes my critical thread to miss events that have catastrophic consequences on my stack.
I tried playing with /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_period_us and /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us as suggested by ubuntu support, but it does not seem to help or sometime create further instability.
Ubuntu support also indicated that "CPU pinning does not isolate kernel thread. Only other user-space applications are guaranteed not to run on the isolated cores."
So my question is there any other flavor of linux that can give me this guarantee ?
If not, what is the ideal approach to work with this limitation, given the fact that I want few threads of my user space application to be absolutely have no contention for CPU

well, userland software has to somehow exchange information with a kernel. it might simply be impossible to do none of that data handling on that CPU, and even if it wasn't, it might be a perfomance-wise terrible idea, as getting data out of one CPU core's cache through memory into another CPU core is really slow, and a source of random latency (read: threat to real-time capability).

atop of that, there might be hardware reasons that a certain core has to handle specific e.g. interrupts.

From what I've dug up you need to patch the kernel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61938639

Do the system freeze logs (if you force dump with sysrq or similar) provide any clues to what part of kernel or which driver is trying to access the isolated core?

I would not expect any flavor of Linux that would operate differently than Ubuntu, because this is kernel-level stuff, and the kernel is used by all flavors of Linux. There may at any given time be a more recent version of a kernel on a particular brand of Linux, which would incorporate changes that would enable this behavior. But I would expect those changes to be included in other distros fairly quickly.
So, if you want some threads to have absolutely no contention, I think you may be out of luck. If the computer is locking up, that means that there are things going on in the kernel that simply cannot be ignored.
There are some websites which discuss CPU isolation issues, for example this one: https://lwn.net/Articles/816298/ ; I'm not sure if the patch was ever released.
This article discusses problems around NVME drives; the decision was made to provide interrupts occur on the same CPU where the request was made: https://serverfault.com/questions/1052448/how-can-i-override-irq-affinity-for-nvme-devices . That URL references NVME interrupts, not kernel threads, but you start to get a flavor for the problems.
Here https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html/tuning_guide/isolating_cpus_using_tuned-profiles-realtime#Isolating_CPUs_Using_tuned-profiles-realtime is something interesting:

Isolating CPUs generally involves:

removing all user-space threads;
removing any unbound kernel threads (bound kernel threads are tied to a specific CPU and may not be moved);
removing interrupts by modifying the /proc/irq/N/smp_affinity property of each Interrupt Request (IRQ) number N in the system.


where you can see that they discuss "bound kernel threads", though they don't discuss the NVME interrupt issue.
In this article, they talk about reducing os jitter due to kernel threads: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.html But I don't see a way to eliminate them. If you want  a cpu all to yourself, you may need to get a microcontroller and interface it to your system on the PCIe bus or some other interface.
I would love to see someone else point to a method that does exactly what you are asking for.

There are a few things you can look into in order to minimize interruptions of your application threads on your isolated cores.
Investigate which kernel threads exactly are running on your isolated cores.
Some kernel threads can easily be moved away by changing their affinity,
i.e. either via taskset/tuna or similar or via workqueue affinity masks or similar.
Next, there are different levels of isolation you can achieve.
For example, if you pin one thread per core then you can also configure them for nohz full operation via the nohz_full= kernel parameter.
From Suse documentation:

What does nohz_full do exactly
When a CPU is included in the cpu-list from the nohz_full boot parameter, the kernel tries to move away from that CPU as much kernel noise as it can.

Note that nohz_full= implies rcu_nocbs=.
That way you also get additional rcu threads that you should move via tuna or similar from your isolated cores to housekeeping cores.
See also some of the low-latency/isolation profiles tuned includes for details and pitfalls on how to change workqueue affinity settings in particular, and other useful and relevant settings, in general.

One thing I should probably add, as you move stuff away from your isolated CPUs: The "housekeeping" CPUs now have to handle certain hardware interrupts, for example for network cards. And threads that are not affined all pile on there too. I have had issues with multicore servers actually dropping some network packets because CPU 0 gets overloaded by all the stuff that the developers thought they could ignore because they had exclusive use of their isolated CPUs.

@MikeS sure, one needs to be careful with such a setup and keep on monitoring, reviewing and testing the whole system with the target workloads. I deliberately used the plural 'housekeeping cores'. Also, when moving stuff away it makes sense to spread it over the non-isolated cores. FWIW, the tuna utility even has a command line argument named 'spread'.
